# Add frameworks to a xcode project using command line

Tags: ios, xcode

We are creating a framework and want to offer an easy way for a user to add it in their project. Possibly a script which will add framework into the project without any xcode interaction.

mod-pbxproj appears to be an option but also looking for other options, preferably shell script based options.

I looked at .pbxproj file and I think it would be straightforward to copy and add framework files, however, some inputs of structure will be appreciated.

**Please do not suggest Cocoapods/Carthage**, we are looking for 100% command line option and both these options require some form of xcode interaction.